# Positionning background-image

Tags: html, css, sass

I would like my image to scroll on the scroll in the leaning block, but once you get to a certain scroll level, you start to see white space appear.

[image]

This is the way I did it

```css
.single-race__s2-container{
  padding: 150px 0 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 1500px;
}

.single-race__s2-container:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
}
.single-race__s2-content{
    transform: skewY(5deg);
}
```

```html
 <div class="single-race__s2">
        <div class="single-race__s2-container"
            style="background-image: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/355/1440/1000.jpg?hmac=QRHj9Ni2849l3Nfu1nLwhURgp2ncK9AsIsQZuXRHfVc')">
            <div class="single-race__s2-content o-wrapper">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                 <span>test</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

am I doing it the right way or is there no solution?

Comment: You need to post generated code so we can actually see the result of what you did

Comment: I edited my post, you should better visualize the problem

Comment: Seems to be working I think

Comment: No, on the scroll, I have a white space that appears

Comment: The white space is part of the empty page that is produced by margin-bottom 600px. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to make sure that when I scroll and the image scrolls in the block that there is no white space, but I don't know if this is possible with my block tilted. The margin was to give the page scroll

Comment: Your background is only on the div, once you scroll past that div then the rest of the page will show which is the white space, if you had content, then you will see content instead of white space. If you want the background image to remain there all the time, then put it on the body

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `clip-path` property. Create a container for your background image, that has the shape you want and load the image as a background-image. Apply position fixed to that container, set the height of the background-image to e.g. double the container height, and then use `overflow: scroll`
That way the background image is scrollable, without showing white space at the bottom.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .image-container {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 100% 80%, 0% 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: scroll;
 }
 .image {
   background-image: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/355/1440/1000.jpg?hmac=QRHj9Ni2849l3Nfu1nLwhURgp2ncK9AsIsQZuXRHfVc);
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   width: 100%;
   height: 600px;
 }
```

Adjust the height as needed and make sure you prefix the clip-path for all standard browsers.